# Set image width dynamically with Eval in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have an image in a repeater in ASP.NET. I need to set the width of this image dynamically to a value returned from the database. I get the information from the SQL db, then I bind the repeater to the result set or datasource and I try to specify the width of the image in the repeater as follows:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width='<%# Eval("ImageSize") %>' ImageUrl="~/Images/ProgressBar.jpg"/>
```

I get an error stating

```
Specified cast is not valid.
```

Could this be caused because of the datatype that is being returned from the db?

Comment: What is field datatype and can it be null ?

Comment: The size cannot be null and the field type returned from DB is Int. Thanks J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Parse` method:

```
<asp:Image 
      ID="Image1" 
      runat="server" 
      Width='<%# System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Parse(Eval("ImageSize").ToString()) %>'
      ImageUrl="~/Images/ProgressBar.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Re-Write in aspx file like this:

```
Width='<%# ConvertToImageSize(Eval("ImageSize")) %>'
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
protected int ConvertToImageSize(object imageSize)
{
  int i = 0;
  if (imageSize != null)
  {
    i = Convert.ToInt32(imageSize); 

   }

  return i;

}
```

A bit rough but I hope you can do the rest of handling at your end easily.

Comment: Thanks for this. Seems a bit tedious compared to @AVD's solution but still a great answer. Thanks J

Comment: I need to set as Percentage not px. how shall i do that?