# how to bind image with specific height and width in repeater control

Tags: asp.net-2.0

i have repeater control that have specific template for my web site jquery slider. how ever i have table name tbl_Slide_master that have slide details to show. this table have two columns like Img_height and Img_width as int data type for setting image properties in repeater control.
for further information i include my repeater control

```
<asp:Repeater ID="SliderRepeater" runat="server">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                  <li>
                   <p class="img"><asp:Image ID="Img_Slide" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "images/"+ Eval("ImageName")%>' Height='<%#Eval("Img_height")%>' Width='<%#Eval("Img_width")%>'/></p>
                   <div class="button"><span class="right_but"><img src="images/l_arrow.gif" alt="picture" width="84" height="28" border="0" /><img src="images/r_arrow.gif" alt="picture" width="84" height="28" border="0" /></span></div>
                   <h2><asp:Label ID="lbl_slideheadertext" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Header_text")%>'></asp:Label></h2>
                   <p><asp:Label ID="lbl_slidetext" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Para_text")%>'></asp:Label></p>
                  </li>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:Repeater>
```

when i run my project then error occured like "Specified cast is not valid". it can not evaluate image height and width properties from tbl_slide_master table. how ever when i simple remove Height and Width properties from Image control then Image shows with original h*w.
is there i have mistake in  Height='<%#Eval("Img_height")%>' and Width='<%#Eval("Img_width")%>...

well i also seen there i can use something like that Height='<%#Eval("Img_height") & "px"%> but also error occurred like "Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'string'"

**Updated Solution**

ok i have idea i can use html image control so no px needed to join with height and width.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="SliderRepeater" runat="server">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                  <li>
                   <%--<p class="img"><asp:Image ID="Img_Slide" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "images/"+ Eval("ImageName")%>' Height='<%# Eval("Img_height")&"px"%>' Width='<%# Eval("Img_width")&"px"%>'/></p>--%>
                   <p class="img"><img id="Img_Slide" src='<%# "images/"+ Eval("ImageName")%>' width='<%#Eval("Img_width")%>' height='<%#Eval("Img_height")%>'/></p>
                   <div class="button"><span class="right_but"><img src="images/l_arrow.gif" alt="picture" width="84" height="28" border="0" /><img src="images/r_arrow.gif" alt="picture" width="84" height="28" border="0" /></span></div>
                   <h2><asp:Label ID="lbl_slideheadertext" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Header_text")%>'></asp:Label></h2>
                   <p><asp:Label ID="lbl_slidetext" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Para_text")%>'></asp:Label></p>
                  </li>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Take a look at this question & answer.  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100130/set-image-width-dynamically-with-eval-in-asp-net)  Use `Height='<%# System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Parse(Eval("ImageHeight").ToString())  %>' `

Comment: its nice but however we can use alternative way to only display image.

Comment: Height='<%#Eval("Img_height")%>px'